# Trying to transpose different groupings of dates under different categories so the column of info goes into a row with the dates organize

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

| Row |
| --- |
| A |
| 1-2-2020 |
| 1-4-2022 |
| B |
| 1-8-2021 |
| C |
| 1-19-2025 |
| 1-2-1923 |
| 4-23-2026 |
| 3-2-2030 |

into

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-2-2020 | 1-8-2021 | 1-19-2025 |
| 1-4-2022 |  | 1-2-1923 |
|  |  | 4-23-2026 |
|  |  | 3-2-2030 |

Comment: You can do this easily in Power Query, if that is an option.

Comment: unfortunately not an option

Answer (score 0):

Formula solution

1] Source data housed in `A1:A10`

2] In "Output" `C1`, formula copied across right :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$10)/(LEN($A$1:$A$10)=1),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

3] In "Output" `C2`, formula copied across right and down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$10)/(LOOKUP(ROW($1:$10),ROW($1:$10)/(LEN($A$1:$A$10)=1),$A$1:$A$10)=C$1),ROW($A2))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I am still having a little bit of trouble, when you say formula copied across the right, is it the same formula in c1 d1 e1?

Comment: also I actually have like 400 entries in column A. do I just change all of the $10 into $400?  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: also what is the meaning of aggregate(15,6 does that require adjustment as well?

Comment: Formula in C1 to E1, this part COLUMN(A1) will change to COLUMN(B1),  COLUMN(C1) in accordingly.

Comment: For 400 entries, just change $10 into $400. That is alright.

Comment: AGGREGATE(15,6,.... is as same as SMALL+IF